# What does single & and single | operators do in flow js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, jestjs

There is a piece of code in one of the files in `react-native` repo [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.44-stable/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/hooks/ReactHostOperationHistoryHook.js#L17) as shown below:

```
export type Operation =
  & {instanceID: DebugID}
  & (
    | {type: 'mount', payload: string}
    | {type: 'insert child', payload: {toIndex: number, content: string}}
    | {type: 'move child', payload: {fromIndex: number, toIndex: number}}
    | {type: 'replace children', payload: string}
    | {type: 'replace text', payload: string}
    | {type: 'replace with', payload: string}
    | {type: 'update styles', payload: mixed /* Style Object */}
    | {type: 'update attribute', payload: {[name: string]: string}}
    | {type: 'remove attribute', payload: string});
```

What are the single `&` and `|` operators supposed to do here?

I am getting an `Unexpected token` error in this file at the first `|` operator when I am running a `jest` test case on my react-native app. I am running node version `5.9.1`. My other team mate who is running node version `8.x` doesn't run into the unexpected token error. So, I am assuming these operators are introduced post node version `5.9.1`. Is that correct?

Comment: As a side note, I would strongly recommend that you and your entire team use the same version of node, at the very least! It's not a great idea to be testing your code on various different environments with different software versions, as you tend to run into a lot of cases of "well, it works on my machine!" An even better solution would be to use something like Vagrant to automatically provision development environments that use the same software versions as your production environment will have.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion in the question. I am aware of the bitwise `&` and `|` operators but I had never before seen these used like this and it was clear that they are not used as bitwise operators in the above code. @sbking is right that they are `flow` types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, these are for Flow types. They represent [Union Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/) and [Intersection Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/). Flow annotations give you static type checking for your code, and here they define the structure that an object must have to be considered a valid `Operation` type by Flow, such as when passing an object to a function that expects an `Operation` argument of this form. They are not an official part of the JS language. To use them, you need to enable flow annotations in babel or use `flow-remove-types`:

https://flow.org/en/docs/install/

However, the `&` and `|` operators do exist in JavaScript, but for [bitwise arithmetic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).